# Four incenters lie on a circle-Does this theorem have a name?

Tags: reference-request, plane-geometry

When I read the new paper [100 CHARACTERIZATIONS OF TANGENTIAL QUADRILATERALS-section 7](https://ijgeometry.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/3.-32-62.pdf), I remember that I posed some problem associated with tangential quadrilateral from 2014 in [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h571304p3357587) and 2015 in [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1095213p5407721) but have no solution until now. This problem is alike to [Christopher Bradley’s conjecture](https://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2011volume11/FG201108.pdf).

I am looking for a proof of the problem.

Let $ABCD$ be a tangential quadrilateral with an inscribed circle $(I)$, Let $P$ be the intersection of the perpendicular bisector of $AC$ and the perpendicular bisector of $BD$. Let $I_A$, $I_B$, $I_C$, $I_D $ are four incenter to triangles $\triangle PAB$, $\triangle PBC$, $\triangle PCD$, $\triangle PDA$ respectively. Let $E_A$, $E_B$, $E_C$, $E_D$ are four excenters to triangles  $\triangle PAB$, $\triangle PBC$, $\triangle PCD$, $\triangle PDA$ opposite the vertex $P$.

[image]

1. The incenters $I_A, I_B, I_C, I_D$ are concyclic.
2. The excenters $E_A, E_B, E_C, E_D $ are concyclic.
3. The centers $I_A, I_C, E_A, E_C$ are concyclic.
4. The centers $I_B, I_D, E_B, E_D$ are concyclic.
5. Center of four circles:  $(I_A, I_B, I_C, I_D)$, $(E_A, E_B, E_C, E_D)$, $(I_A, I_C, E_A, E_C)$, $(I_B, I_D, E_B, E_D)$ are an orthocentric system.
6. $P$ lie on the line joining centers of two circles $(I_A, I_B, I_C, I_D)$ and $(E_A, E_B, E_C, E_D)$.

**Note that**: the problem by Telv Cohl from 2015 [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1095213p4902195) is exactly the same problem as mine from 2014 [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h571304p3357587).